# Does RHEL 7 support Ambient Capabilities?

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd

I am confused about this issue and the google search has limited information.

Some people say they need systemd v229 or higher to support it.

https://github.com/antoiner77/caddy-ansible/issues/31

The update log from Red Hat indicates that support has been available since RHEL 7.3.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/7.3_release_notes/new_features_kernel

But this conflicts with my query results. Which statement is correct? Is there any way to confirm the actual support of the Ambient capabilities?

```
# systemctl --version
systemd 219
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN

# rpm -q centos-release
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Comment: The systemd `AmbientCapabilities` setting was indeed [added in 229](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L4303). The RedHat page says the *kernel* now  supports ambient capabilities. It doesn't say anything about systemd. Is that what you're confused about?

Comment: "*Some people say they need systemd v229 ...*" what is the exact claim? Are you asking can you use ambient capabilities with systemd or in general via command line or programming API?

Comment: @muru Sorry, maybe I didn't express it clearly. I need to add `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` to the `.service` file, but I'm not sure if this will work on centos 7.3 or higher.

Comment: @sebasth Sorry, maybe I didn't express it clearly. I need to add `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` to the `.service` file, but I'm not sure if this will work on centos 7.3 or higher.

Comment: It won't, since you don't have the required systems version (and I don't think Red Hat have patched that in). It might in CentOS 8, maybe (dunno which version that's on, though)

Comment: @muru Is it helpful to upgrade the Linux kernel? Still have to update the systemd version?

Comment: You need support in both, and you have support in the kernel. So if you want to use `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`, a systemd update is also needed.

Comment: @muru Thank for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ambient capabilities](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) is a Linux kernel feature that is available via Linux user-space API. This is what RHEL7.3 release note refer to.

User-space programs also need to have the support for ambient capabilities. `AmbientCapabilities` systemd feature is available since systemd v229, which is newer than the version installed on your system.

Comment: This shows that centos 7 can't currently use `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` in systemd, right? The systemd version in centos 7 stays at 219.

Answer (score 1):

I updated `systemd` from `219.19` to `219.73`, and the `AmbientCapabilities` function was proved to be used normally.